What is a/the definition (if it even exists in literature) of a piecewise continuous function in general topology?
I can't find any information on the web about this.
Definition.
I have a function $f : X \to Y$ between two metric spaces such that there exists a sequence $X_{i}, i \geq 1$ of closed subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcup X_i = X$.  For each $i \geq 1$, there is a continuous function $f_i : X \to Y$ such that $f|_{X_i} = f_i|_{X_i}$, that is $f$ restricted to each $X_i$ coincides with the "piece" of $f_i$ defined on $X_i$.
Compatibility Condition. Also on the overlap $I = \bigcap_{j \in J} X_j$, we have that $f_i|_I = f_j|_I$ for any $J \subset \Bbb{N}$.
This seems a lot like piece-wise continuity setup in $\Bbb{R}$-analysis.
Question. Is $f$ then continuous itself?
Note, in my application I am able to prove that each $f_i : X \to Y$ is actually uniformly continuous, but it probably doesn't matter.  Also, in my application I am able alternatively to construct the $X_i$ to be mutually disjoint so that there is no overlaps.
Attempt. I can can't use the Pasting Lemma because there are an infinite number of closed sets involved.  However, the pasting lemma doesn't require that the $f_i$ agree on overlaps (this is probably a necessary / automatic condition).  So, I have added in the compatibility condition.
The notion of piecewise continuity in $\Bbb{R}$ involves a left/right limit at the "boundary" points of the intervals to ensure that the final function is continuous.  But what's the analog of left vs. right limits in general topology?
Additional Properties.
In my application, both $X,Y$ are Hausdorff, and totally disconnected.  This means (by an Urysohn lemma) if we make the $X_i$ disjoint, then for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and initial sequence $X_1, \dots, X_n$ we can find open $U_i \supset X_i$ such that $U_i \cap U_j = \varnothing$ for $i \neq j$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Ok, take everybody's favorite example of a discontinuous function (I am quite sure you know this one),
$$
f(x)=0, x< 0
$$
$$
f(x)=1, x\ge 0
$$
and restrict it to $X=\mathbb Q$. Now, enumerate rationals, and let $X_i:= \{q_i\}$, where $q_i$ is the $i$-th rational number. As your $f_i$ take the constant function $f_i(x)=f(q_i)$, $x\in X$. This example satisfies all your conditions but is discontinuous.
As for the sentence "I'm not interested in the counter-example per se, but only conditions to "get around it", it will take an effort on your part to figure out how to make an answerable question out of it.
